# I build a React Native Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am facing a problem when the app is running the timer is working correctly however when I reset the timer the countdown timer is stuck in the initial state.

```
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(30)

 useEffect(() => { 
    let interval = setInterval(() => { 
      setTimer(prev => {
        if (prev === 1) clearInterval(interval)
        return prev - 1
      })
    }, 1000)
    newQuestion()
    return () => clearInterval(interval)

  

  }, [])

  const handleReset = () => { 
 setTimer(30)
    setScore(0) 

  }
```

Comment: Initial state you mean at 30?

Comment: Yes but timer is stuck when I press that reset button again once the timer is reach to 0

Comment: The empty array makes the useEffect run only at the initial render. After that the code in it won't execute. Try changing it to either no argument(which will make it run on every re-render) or find a logic around your app specifications(how you want the screen to work and what are the re-render parts)